# Delphi delete FireMonkey element from Form on Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I created an element on my Form with this code in the `OnShow` event:

```
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  VertScrollLink:TVertScrollBox;
begin
  VertScrollLink := TVertScrollBox.Create(form4);
  VertScrollLink.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  VertScrollLink.Parent := form4;
end;
```

On some action, I need to delete the layout dynamically:

```
for LIndex := form4.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
begin
  if (form4.Components[LIndex].ToString='TVertScrollBox') then
  begin
    //showmessage(form4.Components[LIndex].ToString);
    form4.Components[LIndex].Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code works good on Windows, but does not delete anything on Android.

Comment: ARC is burning you. Worth reading up on it. ToString is an odd way to test for type. This isn't PHP. Use the `is` operator. You aren't using XE. I removed that tag.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes i work with PHP too :) i changed the line `if (form4.Components[LIndex].ToString='TVertScrollBox') then` to `if (form4.Components[LIndex] is TVertScrollBox) then` but nothing changed!! the problem seems in `form4.Components[LIndex].Free;` !!!

Comment: Yes I know. ARC is what is hurting you. That's what I said. Why would you expect Free to do anything on ARC. Do you understand ARC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because [Delphi uses Automatic Reference Counting for Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) on mobile platforms (iOS and Android), but not on desktop platforms (Windows and OSX).  Your `Free()` is effectively a no-op, because accessing the component from the `Components[]` property will increment its reference count, and then the `Free()` will decrement it (in fact, the compiler should have issued a warning about the code having no effect).  The component still has active references to it (its `Owner` and `Parent`), so it is not actually freed.

If you want to force the component to be freed, you need to call [`DisposeOf()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.DisposeOf) on it, eg:

```
for LIndex := form4.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
begin
  if form4.Components[LIndex] is TVertScrollBox then
  begin
    form4.Components[LIndex].DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, remove the active references and let ARC handle the destruction normally:

```
var
  VertScrollLink: TVertScrollBox;
  LIndex: Integer;
begin
  ...
  for LIndex := form4.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if form4.Components[LIndex] is TVertScrollBox then
    begin
      VertScrollLink := TVertScrollBox(form4.Components[LIndex]);
      VertScrollLink.Parent := nil;
      VertScrollLink.Owner.RemoveComponent(VertScrollLink);
      VertScrollLink := nil;
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

That being said, you might consider keeping track of the component you create so you don't need to use a loop to find it later:

```
type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    VertScrollLink: TVertScrollBox;
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VertScrollLink := TVertScrollBox.Create(Self);
  VertScrollLink.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  VertScrollLink.Parent := Self;
end;
```

```
begin
  ...
  if Assigned(VertScrollLink) then
  begin
    VertScrollLink.DisposeOf;
    { or:
    VertScrollLink.Parent := nil;
    VertScrollLink.Owner.RemoveComponent(VertScrollLink);
    }
    VertScrollLink := nil;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: why ARC not documented in delphi local help!?

Comment: @roozgar: it is, actually. At least in recent versions. For example, in 10.0 Seattle, this is the local help topic for ARC: `mk:@MSITStore:C:\Program%20Files\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\help\Doc\topics.chm::/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers.htm`