# How to delete TChart (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, teechart

I can't figure out how to delete a `TChart`.  This has to be simple, but I'm not seeing it.  In the TListView `ButtonClick` code below, I delete a series from the active `TChart` and, if the series happens to be the last one, then I want to delete the entire `TChart`.

```
TComponent *T;                     // find chart and delete the selected series
for (int i = 0; i < (Form1->ComponentCount); i++) {
   T = Form1->Components[i];
   if (T->ClassName() == "TChart") {
      int test = T->Tag;
      if (test == TappedChartTag) { //TappedChartTag is global
        if (TChart *TC = dynamic_cast<TChart *>(T)) {
            TC->RemoveSeries(AItem->Index); // this removes the series
            if (TC->SeriesCount()==0) {  // if this was last series, delete chart
               TC->CleanupInstance();
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I can't find a way to completely get rid of the `TChart`.  The `TC->CleanupInstance();` wipes it completely (nothing visible), but the `TChart` is still there.

I'm working in Embarcadero Rad Studio (C++ Builder 10.3 Update 1).

**UPDATE**:  I tried `delete TC;` in place of that `TC->CleanupInstance();` and that works on Win32 but not on iOS.

Comment: `delete TC;` doesn't work on iOS (and Android) because of [ARC reference counting](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers). `TC` is an active reference to the `TChart` object, so its reference count gets incremented when `TC` is assigned. Calling `delete TC;` afterwards simply decrements the reference count, but there are other active references elsewhere, which is why the object does not actually get freed from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the solution Remy provides [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027818/delphi-delete-firemonkey-element-from-form-on-android) I've got it working now.  I just replaced the `TC->CleanupInstance();` with a line to set an integer equal to the components index, `delINT = i`.  Then below the loop that iterates through the components i put this simple code:

```
if (delINT > 0) {
  Form1->Components[delINT]->DisposeOf();
}
```

I was making things much harder than should have been. I couldn't call `DisposeOf()` in my earlier code because it was out of context.  In this case, it works fine (on Win32, iOS, and Android).

Comment: You could simply use `TC->DisposeOf();` instead. No need for `delINT`. You should probably also `break` your loop once you find the matching `TChart`, unless you have multiple `TChart` objects with the same matching `Tag` value (in which case, you should be looping backwards through the `Components[]` array).